# Visual Studio (2008) intellisense and EditorBrowsable attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, servercontrols

I am working on a C# project that involves ASP.NET custom server controls. I have several properties, methods etc that I hide from intellisense using the...

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

...attribute. I also have a web project set up to test these controls. When I reference the web controls as a component in the form of a .dll, the intellisense hides the properties etc fine, but when I reference the web controls via project it shows them.

Is there a reason for this? Is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks
**:)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the thinking is that if you have the project in the solution, you probably are "close enough" to the code to want to see even hidden methods - where-as if you are consuming just a dll, you probably aren't.

There is a community comment with the same symptom in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) (bottom of the page).

Comment: Cheers for that... seems like am not the only one with this little issue!